How to set default state using `Annotation` in `Langgraph`
I am trying to use Annotation to define my state in Langgraph since it seems to be the way they are doing in v0.2. I dont seem to able to set a default value or get the state value from intial state i am passing inside the invoke. I am trying to use the case where we dont have to use a reducer since it is will automatically replace the value with the last value. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
import { END, START, StateGraph, Annotation } from "@langchain/langgraph";
import { AIMessage, BaseMessage } from "@langchain/core/messages";

// Define the state structure with channels
const ConfigState = Annotation.Root({
    greeting: Annotation<string>({ default: "Bonjour!" }), // Set the default value here
    messages: Annotation<BaseMessage[]>({
        reducer: (left: BaseMessage[], right: BaseMessage | BaseMessage[]) => {
            if (Array.isArray(right)) {
                return left.concat(right);
            }
            return left.concat([right]);
        },
        default: () => [],
    }),
});

console.log(ConfigState);

const callModel1 = async (state: typeof ConfigState.State) => {
    console.log(`-----message inside callModel1 @ start-----: `, state.greeting);
    return { greeting: "Hola!" }; // Update the greeting with the new value
};

const callModel2 = async (state: typeof ConfigState.State) => {
    console.log(`-----message inside callModel2 @ start-----: `, state.greeting);
    return { greeting: "Hi!" }; // Update the greeting with the new value
};

// Create the workflow with the main node and end node
const workflow = new StateGraph(ConfigState)
    .addNode("agent", callModel1)
    .addNode("agent2", callModel2)
    .addEdge(START, "agent")
    .addEdge("agent", "agent2")
    .addEdge("agent2", END); // Connect the agent node to the END node

const initialState = { greeting: "Hello!" }; // Define your initial state here

const result = await workflow.compile().invoke({ state: initialState }); // Pass the initial state when invoking the workflow

console.log(result);

results:
AnnotationRoot {
  lc_graph_name: 'AnnotationRoot',
  spec: {
    greeting: LastValue {
      ValueType: undefined,
      UpdateType: undefined,
      lc_graph_name: 'LastValue',
      value: undefined
    },
    messages: BinaryOperatorAggregate {
      ValueType: undefined,
      UpdateType: undefined,
      lc_graph_name: 'BinaryOperatorAggregate',
      value: [],
      operator: [Function: reducer],
      initialValueFactory: [Function: default]
    }
  }
}
-----message inside callModel1 @ start-----:  null
-----message inside callModel2 @ start-----:  Hola!
{ greeting: 'Hi!', messages: [] }


We cannot use Annotation<string>() with a default value since it uses LastValue in the background which does not accept a default value. We can only pass values in the state. To get the same functionality, we need to extend Annotation by creating pseudo reducer function and pass the default
// Helper function to create an Annotation with default value behavior
function AnnotationWithDefault<T>(defaultValue: T) {
    return Annotation<T>({
        value: (currentValue: T, update?: T) => update || currentValue, // Prioritize update value
        default: () => defaultValue, // Set default value
    });
}

we can then do :
// Define the state structure with a default value for greeting
const GraphAnnotation = Annotation.Root({
    greeting: AnnotationWithDefault("Hola!"), // Only pass the default value
});

